# Why server is running on undefined after using dotenv?

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I am facing problem while using dotenv in my project and it showing like 'server is running bro on---> undefined'

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express= require ('express')
const mongoose=require ('mongoose')
const connectDb = require('./config/config')
const productRoute=require('./routes/ProductRoute')
connectDb()

const app=express()

app.use('/api',productRoute)

const port=process.env.PORT
app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running bro on---> ${port}`);
    
})
```

Comment: the call to .config() returns an object, log it out to check for errors

Comment: Try `const { error, parsed } = require('dotenv').config(); console.log(error); console.log(parsed)` to see what happens.

Comment: The location of the `.env` file matters. If the `.env` file is in a different directory than the main file, you need to provide the absolute path to the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have `PORT` defined in your `.env` file?  I tried out your code, and it works for me.